# Receber um inteiro e uma string e armazenar em 2 vetores em C?

Tags: c

Estou aprendendo C e estou travado em um exercício que pede para armazenar os dados da seguinte forma.

Nota do Aluno e Nome do Aluno na mesma linha, e depois com um índice escolhido determinar a situação do aluno, a parte de manipular o índice e verificar a nota dele eu sei fazer, mas estou com problemas em como seria fazer esse tipo de problema usando vetores em C que receber um inteiro e uma string que passa para  2 vetores.

Exemplo dos dados:

```
8.0 Ed Rex
9.0 Marcos Vice 
1.0 Alan Pequenuxo
```

Esse seria o meu codigo

```
include stdio.h
include stdlib.h
include string.h

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    int nota[99];
    char aluno[20][30];
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (i=0 ;i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d %s",&nota[i], &aluno[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: E que problema está tendo?

Comment: aparece esse erro quando tento compilar. 

nomes.c: In function ‘main’:
nomes.c:12:10: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char (*)[30]’ [-Wformat=]
    scanf("%d %s",&nota[i], &aluno[i]);
          ^

Comment: Troque:    &aluno[i] por aluno[i] no scanf (tire o &).

Comment: valeu amigo, nem acredito que era só por causa disso.
mas se eu quisesse que ele guardasse o nome com sobrenome, o que eu poderia fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o modo mais correto de resolver o seu problema é agregar o que é comum em uma estrutura. Assim, a nota e o nome pertencem à estrutura Aluno. Portanto, o seu programa ficaria do seguinte modo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Aluno
{
    float nota;
    char nome[100];
} Aluno;

int main()
{
    int n = 0, i = 0;
    Aluno aluno[30];
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%f %100[0-9a-zA-Z ]",&aluno[i].nota, aluno[i].nome);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%f %s\n", aluno[i].nota, aluno[i].nome);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note no `scanf` uma diretiva estranha: `%100[0-9a-zA-Z ]`. Ela se parece com um regex e permite que vc formate exatamente o que quer como entrada para o campo `aluno[i].nome`. Em outra palavras, vai aceitar uma quantidade máxima de 100 caracteres, onde eles podem ser de 0-9, a-z, A-Z e/ou espaço em branco.

Se quiser usar caracteres acentuados, pode substituí-la também por: `%100[^\n]`. Ou seja, lê qualquer coisa até o final da linha

Comment: A única coisa que desgostei foi usar uma `struct` para o cenário em que o AP está aprendendo ainda o básico. De toda sorte +1

Comment: estou aprendendo mesmo, mas essa parte do struct pode me ajudar para problemas futuros que necessitem desse raciocínio.obrigado pela ajuda tambem